# Link to add associated item in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a model called sections, which has many feedbacks. This is working ok, and on the 'section' show page I can show the associated 'feedbacks' like so:

```
<% @section.feedbacks.each do |feedback| %> 
  <%= feedback.name %> 
  <%= link_to 'Show', feedback %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_feedback_path(feedback) %> |
<% end %>
```

Works fine. But now I need a button that takes me to the create page for a new feedback item, and it needs to be associated to this 'section'.

At first I did it with a nested form, but the feedback items have quite a lot of fields and so it's messy to do it all on one page.

I'm new to ruby, so hopefully it's a really simple thing!

Thanks in advance for any help,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested form for it. If your form contains many fields then use bootstrap wizard for it.

or

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_feedback_path(section_id: @section.id) %>
```

& in your new method of `feedback_controller` , write the below:

```
 @feedback = Feedback.new
 @feedback.section_id = params[:section_id]
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid using tabs ideally.

Comment: So, you don't want all the fields neither in a single page nor in tabs. So save only those fields which are mandatory for your business logic

Comment: I want all the fields in a single page, i'm just not sure how to create that link to create a new item form it's associated item.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is pretty much standard Rails stuff and you need to read a bit more of the official guides. You will need:

- A controller with different actions for feedbacks (`edit` and `new` for example)
- Some views for the above actions. The `edit` and `new` views can share the same form.
- Routing to make it possible to work with a `Feedback` in the context of a `Section`.

Like:

```
resources :sections do
  resources :feedbacks
end
```

This will allow you to use the following instead of your edit link:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_feedback_path([@section, feedback]) %>
```

And will go to this edit route:

```
/sections/:section_id/feedbacks/:feedback_id
```

You will also have the following new route available:

```
/sections/:section_id/feedbacks/new
```

Which will allow you to get the right section from the url params in order to create a feedback for it.